# Replacing strings including colon by latex3

Tags: expl3, latex3

I would like to replace such as `:a` into `à`. The following is the code

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\str_new:N \replace_str
\cs_new:Npn \my_replace:n #1
{
 \str_set:Nn \replace_str {#1}
 \str_replace_all:Nnn \replace_str { :a } { à }
 \str_use:N \replace_str
}

\NewDocumentCommand \replace { m }
{
 \my_replace:n { #1 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Though this can show `à`, even control sequences are dealt as strings.
Then I used `\tl_` instead of `\str_`.

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \replace_str
\cs_new:Npn \my_replace:n #1
{
 \tl_set:Nn \replace_str {#1}
 \tl_replace_all:Nnn \replace_str { :a } { à }
 \tl_use:N \replace_str
}

\NewDocumentCommand \replace { m }
{
 \my_replace:n { #1 }
}
```

However, it does not show `à` but `:a`.

How can I get `à` with dealing control sequences as so.

Comment: please fix your examples so that people can run them and debug the issue, they are just fragments currently that can't be run and don't have an example of the command being called

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem are catcodes: Between `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff`, the catcode of `:` is 'letter' instead of 'other'.
The `tl` functions differentiate between catcodes, so the colon in the code block is different from the colon in the rest of the document.
Happily a colon with catcode 'other' is saved in `\c_colon_str`, so this can be used instead. Of course, `\c_colon_str` has to be expanded, so we use `\tl_replace_all:Nfn`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_replace_tl
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_replace_all:Nnn { Nfn }
\cs_new:Npn \my_replace:n #1
{
 \tl_set:Nn \l_replace_tl {#1}
 \tl_replace_all:Nfn \l_replace_tl { \c_colon_str a } { à }
 \tl_use:N \l_replace_tl
}

\NewDocumentCommand \replace { m }
{
 \my_replace:n { #1 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\replace{abc:abc\LaTeXe}
\end{document}
```

I also replaced `\replace_tl` with `\l_replace_tl` because variables in `expl3` always come with a scope prefix, here it is `l_` for local.

[image]